# AngularJS values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How do I get the `FirstName` value in my directive?

```html
<hello-World value="{{item.FirstName}}"> </hello-World>
```

```js
app.directive('helloWorld', function() {
return {
  restrict: 'AE',
  replace: 'true',
  template: '<h3>Hello ??????</h3>'
 }; 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get values you need to use `scope` parameter in directive. Read more from directives here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Check this example

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('helloWorld', function() {
return {
  restrict: 'AE',
  replace: 'true',
  template: '<h3>Hello {{value}}</h3>',
  scope: {
      value: '@'
    },
 }; 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">

<hello-World value='World' />

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
app.directive('helloWorld', function() {
return {
  restrict: 'AE',
  replace: 'true',
  template: '<h3>Hello {{value}}</h3>',
  scope: {
     value: '='
  }
 }; 
});
```